# wix: get install location from custom dll

Tags: c++, dll, wix, custom-action

I have a problem with WiX and C++ custom actions DLL: I want to get the installation location specified in the .wxs file from custom action dll, I am using WcaGetTargetPath, but this API doesn't work. Anyone any idea how to do achieve this?

WiX file:

```
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)" Name="PFiles">
        <Directory Id="CompanyDir" Name="ABC">
          <Directory Id="PCMINSTALLDIR" Name="ClientMonitor">
            <Directory Id="STDSCIPTSDIR" Name="standard_scripts">
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="CSTMSCIPTSDIR" Name="custom_scripts">
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
.....
 <CustomAction Id="ChangeConfig"
                  BinaryKey="PcmConfig"
                  DllEntry="ModifyConfigFile"
                  Execute="deferred"
                  Return="check"
                  Impersonate="no"
                  HideTarget="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ChangeConfig" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>

Custom Action method:

    LPWSTR pwzTargetPath = NULL;
    hr = WcaGetTargetPath(L"PCMINSTALLDIR", &pwzTargetPath);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to get the PCM installation path.");
```

Comment: What's the hresult value? When you say "doesn't work" are you sure the CA is being called and not failing to load because of a missing dependency?

Comment: it's loaded since my break point was hit and from the debugger, I saw pwzTargetPath  is empty